# how to pass every line from a text file as an argument in rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

i have made this code to check for alive urls in a text file it was first to check for a single url the script worked but then i wanted  to make it multithreaded i got this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSCQu.png)

here is the original code :

```
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use hyper::Client;
use tokio::io::BufReader;



#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {

    let https = HttpsConnector::new();
    let url = std::env::args().nth(1).expect("no list given");
    let client = Client::builder().build::<_, hyper::Body>(https);

    let reader = BufReader::new(url);
    let lines = reader.lines(); 
      

for l in lines {    

    let sep = l.parse()?;

   // Await the response...
    let resp = client.get(sep).await?;

if resp.status() == 200 {
   println!("{}", l);}

if resp.status() == 301 {
   println!("{}", l); }

   }


     Ok(())    
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 4):

the issue seems to be that you are passing in the file's *name* as opposed to its *content* to the `BufReader`.

In order to read the contents instead, you can use a `tokio::fs:File`.
Here's an example of reading a file and printing its lines to stdout using tokio and a `BufReader`:

```rust
use tokio::{
    fs::File,
    io::{
        // This trait needs to be imported, as the lines function being
        // used on reader is defined there
        AsyncBufReadExt,
        BufReader
    }
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // get file command line argument
    let file_argument = std::env::args().nth(1).expect("Please provide a file as command line argument.");
    // open file
    let file = File::open(file_argument).await.expect("Failed to open file");
    // create reader using file
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    // get iterator over lines
    let mut lines = reader.lines();

    // this has to be used instead of a for loop, since lines isn't a
    // normal iterator, but a Lines struct, the next element of which
    // can be obtained using the next_line function.
    while let Some(line) = lines.next_line().await.expect("Failed to read file") {
        // print current line
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ...i'm still new to rust and the lack of documentation made it hard a bit for me ..the code works perfectly

Comment: Pffffftttt. I was dealing with this cryptic "Iterator not implemented" error for more than an hour... Didn't even consider the possibility that `Lines` struct is simply not an iterator. Bizzare design choice if you ask me.